Recommended access practice for blob storage
As we are building a Saas application and there is a requirement where we want to store some of the bills as azure blobs inside the container now for creating a blob inside the container via a REST API ( here we are using nodejs) , I found two options to complete the process

Creating a Role assignment and assigning it as role permissions
Through creating SAS tokens with some specifications like user delegation keys

I want to know which practice is recommended for this non human robot automation approach to create blobs inside a container
Is role assignments through service principle is vulnerable ? , if yes then what about SAS and its periodic request for token and validating it ? , any docs for reference will be helpful .


Is role assignments through service principle is vulnerable ? , if yes then what about SAS and its periodic request for token and validating it ? , any docs for reference will be helpful .

For automation approach to create blobs inside a container, I would suggest you choose RBAC where continuous, long-term access is required, using a service principal with appropriate RBAC roles like Storage Blob Data Contributor you can be able to access it.
Where SAS tokens are provide time-limited access to specific resources (like a container or a blob) and specific permissions (like write or list). So, SAS token will helpful scenarios like access needs are temporary or periodic.

Is role assignments through service principle is vulnerable ? ,


If their credentials are exposed or not well-managed the Service principals can be risky.
To resolve this, it's important to regularly change the credentials and enforce strict access controls.

Here is the node.js code to authenticate using the service principal and create a blob in Azure Blob Storage.
First create service principal and assign role Storage Blob Data contributor role using this MS-Document.
Code:

const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const { BlobServiceClient } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

// Replace with your values
const accountName = "venkat32xxx3";
const containerName = "sample";
const blobName = "test.txt";
const content = "Hello, World!";

// Authenticate using DefaultAzureCredential
const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(`https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net`, credential);

async function createBlob() {
  try {
    const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
    await containerClient.createIfNotExists();
    const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName);
    await blockBlobClient.upload(content, Buffer.byteLength(content));
    console.log(`Blob "${blobName}" is uploaded successfully.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading blob:', error);
  }
}

For configuration, store the service principal credentials as environment variables.
AZURE_CLIENT_ID=<your-client-id>
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=<your-client-secret>
AZURE_TENANT_ID=<your-tenant-id>

Output:
Blob "test.txt" is uploaded successfully.



The same is decided by me but the thing i want to clarify is why the RBAC is required for the top level heirarchy or am i wrong with that , is iam role assignment within container level is not enough ?

If you need to access particular container, you can assign rbac role to container level.
